# Examples of bijective polynomials $\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ that aren't linear.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to construct a polynomial automorphism $P:\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$ that isn't just a linear function like $P=(x,2y)$.

I know that such a mapping must have constant non-zero Jacobian determinant, so for $n=1$ linearity is a must, however for $n\ge2$ I don't see why we couldn't have something more interesting.

I can construct some "not quite linear" maps like $(x,y+x^2)$ or $(x,y+z,x(y+z)+y)$, but they are still "essentially linear" since we can more or less ignore the non-linear parts. (I can formalize this, but hopefully, it makes intuitive sense from the examples.)

I have read some surveys on the Jacobian conjecture, and I don't think it rules out non-trivial bijective polynomial mappings even if it is true.

Am I missing any obvious functions? Or is it unknown whether such functions exist?

Comment: You can compose several "not quite linear maps", say $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y+f_1(x))$ with $(x,y) \mapsto (x + g_1(y),y)$ then with $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y+f_2(x))$ and so on.

Comment: Right, but I still consider them basically linear, since I can "peel off" the variables one by one (possible after a linear transform of the variables).  I wonder if the is a bijective mapping that doesn't use this principle.

Comment: Not sure how useful this is but by Ax-Grothendieck it's enough to find injective examples

Comment: Look for Nagata's example in connection to automorphism of affine spaces.

Comment: @Mohan can you give a few more details? The Nagata examples I can Google seem to assume an infinite number of indeterminates..?

Comment: @Mohan Ah, I think I found it: https://www.pnas.org/content/100/22/12561 That's indeed very nice. Do you want to add it as an answer to this question?